# Does JQgrid pagination displays 1 of 0 if there are no records to display in JSON?

Tags: json, jqgrid, pagination

I am implementing JQgrid for JSON with jqGrid  4.3.1. If there are no records, json object look like this.

```
{"partabtxt":{" detA":[],"detA1":[],"detB":[]},"partctxt":{"detC":[]},"partdtxt":{"detC":[]},"partetxt":{"detC":[]}}
```

But pagination is showing Page 1 0f 0 with right hand side buttons highlighted.

My question is 
1) Is this out of box functionality in JQgrid to show Page 1 of 0 if there are no records?
2) Is there any way to get page 0 of 0 if there are no records?

I have tried for one of the below solution provided

```
beforeRequest: function() {
  if (mydata.length === 0) {
                  grid[0].p.page = 0;     
              }
```

},

but this solution is not working fine for json object, as it sometimes throwing null pointer exception, sometimes picking the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify page and record count in your json response

```
{"total":1.0,"page":1,"records":1,"rows":[{"id":001,"cell":[001,"record1"}]}
```